# How to dynamically change innerHTML with checkbox between two values with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, woocommerce

I'm a little stumped here. I'm using pure JavaScript, no jQuery.

I want to change the innerHTML of a heading between two values when a checkbox is selected. I have it working when the checkbox is selected, but unchecking the checkbox does not switch it back.

[JSFiddle!](https://jsfiddle.net/sackadelic/xrucspng/8/)

**HTML**

```
<h2 id="billing-information-header"></h2>

<p id="before-billing">Please enter your billing information below. Shipping to a different address? Check the box below the billing fields.</p>

<h2>SHIPPING INFORMATION:</h2>

<input id="ship-to-different-address-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="ship_to_different_address"><span>Ship to a Different Address?</span>
```

**JS**:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        const checkBox = document.querySelector('#ship-to-different-address-checkbox');
        const heading = document.querySelector('#billing-information-header');
        const message = document.querySelector('#before-billing');

        heading.innerHTML = 'BILLING & SHIPPING INFORMATION:';

        checkBox.addEventListener('click', function() {
            heading.innerHTML = 'BILLING INFORMATION:';
        });

});
```

I'm planning on switching the `heading` back to 'BILLING & SHIPPING INFORMATION" upon unchecking the box. I'm also planning on dynamically changing the `message` inner HTML as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the checked property of the checkbox to determine if it's checked

here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/978ucdgt/

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  const checkBox = document.querySelector('#ship-to-different-address-checkbox');
  const heading = document.querySelector('#billing-information-header');
  const message = document.querySelector('#before-billing');

  heading.innerHTML = 'BILLING & SHIPPING INFORMATION:';

  checkBox.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    heading.innerHTML = e.target.checked ? 'BILLING INFORMATION:' : 'BILLING & SHIPPING INFORMATION:'

  });

});
```

```html
<h2 id="billing-information-header"></h2>

<p id="before-billing">Please enter your billing information below. Shipping to a different address? Check the box below the billing fields.</p>

<h2>SHIPPING INFORMATION:</h2>

<input id="ship-to-different-address-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="ship_to_different_address"><span>Ship to a Different Address?</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.

```
checkBox.addEventListener('click', function() {
            if(!checkBox.checked) {
            heading.innerHTML = 'BILLING INFORMATION:';
          }
          else {
            heading.innerHTML = 'BILLING & SHIPPING INFORMATION:';
          }
}
```